# vue.js unit tests : Why my component is undefined?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

I am trying to set up a unit test as following :

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import ChangeTitleComponent from '@/components/ChangeTitleComponent'
    import store from '@/vuex/store'

    describe('ChangeTitleComponent.vue', () => {
      describe('changeTitle', () => {
        var component

        beforeEach(() => {
          var vm = new Vue({
            template: '<div><h2>{{ title }}</h2> <change-title-component :title="title" :id="id"></change-title-component></div>',
            components: {
              ChangeTitleComponent
            },
            props: ['title', 'id'],
            store
          }).$mount()
          component = vm.$refs.changetitlecomponent
        })

        component.title = 'Groceries'
        component.id = '1'

        it('should log the component', () => {
          console.log('CHANGE TITLE COMPONENT: ', component)
        })
      })
    })
```

but when I run it, I get an error ...

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined

Why my component is 'undefined ' ?

thanks for feedback

Comment: I can't see `ref` attribute on `<change-title-component>` called `changetitlecomponent`.
Try like this `<change-title-component ref="changetitlecomponent" :title="title" :id="id"></change-title-component>`

Comment: thanks a lot ... this is the first error ..  need to add it !, second error : setting component.title and and component.id should be done inside the second it('should...) block !!  if you want to add it as an answer , you're welcome.. I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you forgot to add `ref` attribute to the component in template, so in fact property `changetitlecomponent` doesn't exist on `vm.$refs`.

This should fix problem.

```
<change-title-component ref="changetitlecomponent" :title="title" :id="id"></change-title-component>
```

> Found by author: Setting the properties to the component object should
>   be moved into the `it` block of unit test.